# Disable logging for FastAPI Form data

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I have couple of Form() parameters (using the OAuth2PasswordRequestForm of FastAPI) in an endpoint as below, and a global logging configuration. When I enable the logging to have DEBUG level I got the following logs and I would like to disable them. Is this possible?

```
@app.post("/token")
async def token(response: Response, auth: Annotated[OAuth2PasswordRequestForm, Depends()]):
    return
```

Basic logging configuration

```
logging.basicConfig(level=self.level, handlers=[self.handler]) # stream handler
```

And I got the following logs:

```
2023-05-29 12:25:19 - DEBUG - Calling on_part_begin with no data
2023-05-29 12:25:19 - DEBUG - Calling on_header_field with data[54:73]
2023-05-29 12:25:19 - DEBUG - Calling on_header_value with data[75:101]
2023-05-29 12:25:19 - DEBUG - Calling on_header_end with no data
2023-05-29 12:25:19 - DEBUG - Calling on_headers_finished with no data
2023-05-29 12:25:19 - DEBUG - Calling on_part_data with data[105:110]
2023-05-29 12:25:19 - DEBUG - Calling on_part_end with no data
2023-05-29 12:25:19 - DEBUG - Calling on_part_begin with no data
2023-05-29 12:25:19 - DEBUG - Calling on_header_field with data[166:185]
2023-05-29 12:25:19 - DEBUG - Calling on_header_value with data[187:213]
2023-05-29 12:25:19 - DEBUG - Calling on_header_end with no data
2023-05-29 12:25:19 - DEBUG - Calling on_headers_finished with no data
2023-05-29 12:25:19 - DEBUG - Calling on_part_data with data[217:222]
2023-05-29 12:25:19 - DEBUG - Calling on_part_end with no data
2023-05-29 12:25:19 - DEBUG - Calling on_end with no data
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to prevent those logs was to change the log level of the multipart internal logger (since Form data uses multipart)

```
logging.getLogger("multipart").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```